# Issue Installing nokogiri 1.5.10 on SUSE Enterprise Server 11 SP3

Tags: rubygems, nokogiri, libxml2, suse

I am attempting to install version 1.5.10 of the ruby gem "nokogiri" on an instance of SUSE Enterprise Server 11 SP3 (x86_64). Upon executing (as root):

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.5.10
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... no
-----
libxml2 is missing please visit [...]
```

The output of:

```
rpm -qa | grep libxml2
```

Shows that the following packages are installed:

```
libxml2-python-2.7.6-0.23.1
libxml2-devel-2.7.8-15.1
libxml2-32bit-2.7.6-0.23.1
libxml2-27.6-0.23.1
```

I have verified that `/usr/includes/libxml2/libxml/parser.h` exists, and have even tried to force referencing of the location via passing it to the `gem install` command as:

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.5.10 -- --with-xml2-includes=/user/includes/libxml2/
```

However the result is the same. Any suggestions on resolving this error would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on SLES 11.3. I had to install libxslt-devel in addition to libxml2-devel.
Try

```
zypper in libxslt-devel
```

Comment: That reports 'up to date'; updated 'libxml2-devel' as well.  No change - cannot install rails on OpenSuse.

Answer (score 0):

First step :

```
zypper in libxml2-devel libxslt-devel
```

Second step :

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
```